# jQuery not validating RadioButtonList properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I want to use jQuery to validate `RadioButtonList` to ensure that user has checked on one of the values. If the user doesn't check on any of the radio buttons, an alert appears. However, the problem is that even after the user has checked on one of the radio buttons, the alert still prompts. The following jQuery codes I have seemed to be correct according to what I found online.

This is my `RadioButtonList`:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbClass" runat="server" CssClass="rbClass">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Asset Management Tool" Value="Asset Management Tool"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Backup Tool" Value="Backup Tool"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Communication Tool" Value="Communication Tool"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Developer Tool" Value="Developer Tool"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
if ($('#rbClass').is(':checked') == false) {   
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
    alert("Please select the software's classification.");
}
```

As you can see, I've tried a few different ways of checking if the `RadioButtonList` has been checked. I've also tried using the `CssClass` attribute (`.rbClass`) to validate, and it doesn't work as expected either. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the ASP controls directly through javascript, since those controls will rendered as HTML so its Id will be changed and it will be related to the parent. So what you can do here is,  Use its Client ID like the following:

```
var selectedCount=$("#<%=rbClass.ClientID %> input:checked").length;
if(selectedCount==0)
{
    // Statements here nothing is checked
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but the problem still persists; the alert still shows.

Answer (score 0):

I found these examples from the internet..

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function Validate()
{
   var RB1 = document.getElementById("<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%>");
   var radio = RB1.getElementsByTagName("input");
   var isChecked=false;
   for (var i=0;i<radio.length;i++)
   {
       if (radio[i].checked)
       {
           isChecked=true;
           break;
       }
   }
   if(!isChecked)
   {
        alert("Please select an item");
   }
   return isChecked;
}
</script>
```

More reference on [validate-aspnet-radiobuttonlist](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/07/validate-aspnet-radiobuttonlist-using.html), [ASP.Net-RadioButtonList-Control.aspx](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-JavaScript-with-ASP.Net-RadioButtonList-Control.aspx)

Comment: Link only answers are not permitted, Please consider adding valuable points from the link to the answer, then attach link as reference